# Secondary screen gets locked when a full screen program opens on it

Tags: release-juno, display

I have a laptop (primary screen) with a connected monitor (second screen).

When some program (for example, a video, a game...) is opened full screen on the monitor, it gets locked and the image doesn't refresh (for a video, it gets stuck at the first frame, although it continues playing both audio and video...)

However, this is only happening if the program is opened full screen directly in the monitor, not in the laptop screen.

One solution I found when this happens is to move the program to the primary screen (Cmd + Shift + Left Arrow) and then move it again to the monitor (Cmd + Shift + Right Arrow). This way, it shows correctly on the secondary screen.

Any ideas why is this happening? Is there some fix for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been recently fixed: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/404

Waiting for the fix update :)